# Does Plague do more damage if I stand in the middle of it?

Tags: diablo-iii

I play a melee class, and it seems like I take more damage if I stand in the center of the green void zones caused by [Plagued](http://www.diablowiki.com/Plagued) monsters

Do I take more damage from standing in the center of plague?

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe when you stand in the middle you're actually standing on two overlapping zones and taking twice as much damage.

Answer (score 2):

Other than with other area damage spells, plague stacks with itself meaning that damage can and will increase if a melee never moves out of the first plague when the champ recasts the spell.